# sql query to retrieve data from 2 tables using join

Tags: mysql, database, join, error-handling, inner-join

using sql query to retrieve data from 2 tables using join  did not work as i want this is the used query:

```
$result2 = $wpdb->get_results('select site_info.siteID, owner_info.ownerNAME, 
                            site_info.siteNAME,  site_info.equipmentTYPE 
                            from `site_info`
                                INNER JOIN `owner_info` on site_info.ownerID = owner_info.ownerID
                            where owner_info.ownerID = 159');
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    echo join(', ',  $result), '<br/>';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

where i am retrieving data from 2 tables but the result is:

```
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/wp-portfolio/search-info.php on line 43
```

if anyone can tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you try executing the query in MySQL console and see if that returns any result?

Comment: yes i already try it and it return the required result... the problem is in join() function  but i do not know what is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join() is a php function alias to implode()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

your second argument passed to join() is not an array, but the join method requires an array as a second parameter, this causes the problem

$result is an object with this form :
stdClass Object ( [siteID] => BAH004 [siteNAME] =>XXXXXXX [equipmentTYPE] => XXXXXXX )

Maybe try something like this :

```
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    echo join(', ',  array($result->siteID, $result->ownerNAME, $result->siteNAME, $result->equipmentTYPE)), '<br/>';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

you can also try this maybe simplier :

```
foreach($result2 as $result) {
    $result = (array)$result; // convert the object to an array
    echo join(', ',  $result), '<br/>';
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help let me understand right what you said that the join() function doesn't take an array ?

Comment: I mean your second parameter is not a simple array, but it's more than that, your second parameter is an object not an array. I edit my answer to better comprehension

Comment: The second solution fits more your need